# Toolbar with text

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I have a Toolbar with text "App de prueba" and a menu icon, but the app name is on the left side, how can delete the app name?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `setTitle()` method in your activity's onCreate and pass an empty String in it - `setTitle("")` (assuming you are using a custom layout as title in your toolbar). You cannot remove or change the visibility of the title view in the activity as the id of this view is not public. There are ways by which you can still access the id by using reflection but that makes the code messy and therefore is not needed.